# What is the best way to force rotation on a view controller that isn't visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, rotation, screen-rotation

I've looked around Stack Overflow and haven't found anything that addresses my exact problem. I'm working on an app that uses a custom tab view to switch between 4 different navigation controllers. The problem I'm facing is that when rotating the device and then switching to a different tab, the view controller that becomes visible is still layed out for the old orientation. I've been using `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to perform whatever orientation-specific preparation I want using the new orientation, which works as expected when the VC is visible, but I understand that the rotation methods aren't called for view controllers which are not visible at the time of rotation.

Apple's documentation says:

> #### Rotations May Occur When Your View Controller Is Hidden
>
> If your view controller’s contents are not onscreen when a rotation occurs, then it does not see the list of rotation messages. For example, consider the following sequence of events:
>
> 1. Your view controller presents another view controller’s contents full screen.
> 2. The user rotates the device so that the user interface orientation changes.
> 3. Your app dismisses the presented view controller.
>
> In this example, the presenting view controller was not visible when the rotation occurred, so it does not receive any rotation events. Instead, when it reappears, its views are simply resized and positioned using the normal view layout process. If your layout code needs to know the current orientation of the device, it can read the app object’s statusBarOrientation property to determine the current orientation.

I've come up with some ideas to deal with this, but I'm not sure what's best. They each have their pros and cons. My current solution is basically to duplicate whatever I'm doing in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` in `viewWillAppear` so that a view controller which was not visible when rotation occurred can make adjustments for the new orientation before it becomes visible. My other idea was to move my orientation code from `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` into `viewWillLayoutSubviews` which gets called both when the view controller is rotated while visible, and when it becomes visible after having not been. The trouble with that is that layout methods can be called quite frequently even when no rotation has occurred. Yet another option is to register my view controllers for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, which I imagine my VCs will receive regardless of whether or not they are visible, although I haven't tested this out.

I imagine this is a pretty common problem and I'm wondering-- What are everyone else's solutions? Is there a better way to deal with this than the solutions I've come up with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding an observer on the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification should help you achieve it

Comment: I didn't see your response until now. Thanks for the input, this is how I ended up doing things.